# How to set a mouse Listener that it cannot be clicked in another table?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtable, mouseevent

I have one Table with Playlists. When I double click on a Playlist I get Movies for this Playlist.

However, when I double click on the movies I get an empty table back. Consequently, I do not want to click in the movie table. How to prevent this behaviour?

That's my listener:

```
playlistTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {

            JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
            int row = target.getSelectedRow();

            videoTableModel = new VideoTableModel(playlistService.getMoviesOfPlaylist(row));
            target.setModel(videoTableModel);

            movieTable.setEnabled(true);

            createPlaylist.setEnabled(false);
            setButtonIcon("icons\\playlist_grau.png", createPlaylist, "createPlaylist");

            removePlaylist.setEnabled(false);
            setButtonIcon("icons\\bin_grau.png", removePlaylist, "removePlaylist");

            playlistTable.setEnabled(false);

            revalidate();

        }
    }
});
```

I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Either remove the mouse listener from the table, or set a flag that will make the listener do nothing:

```
playlistTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    private boolean ignoreDoubleClicks = false;

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && !ignoreDoubleClicks) {
            JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
            target.removeMouseListener(this);
```

or

```
playlistTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    private boolean ignoreDoubleClicks = false;

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && !ignoreDoubleClicks) {
                ignoreDoubleClicks = true;
                ...
```

Comment: Thx for your answer!!! My "new" Problem is that when I want to double click again on the table I the ignoreDoubleClicks stays on true. How to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same table to represent both sets of data

```
 JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
 ....
 target.setModel(videoTableModel);
```

Option 1) remove the listener when you change to "video mode"

```
 target.removeMouseListener(this);
```

Option 2) add a variable and set it to false when you change to "video mode", if the variable is false do nothing.

Option 3) depends of the rest of your code, check the class of the current model (it assumes you have a different one for playlists)

```
  if (!(target.getModel instanceof VideoTableModel)) {
    [Your code here]
  }
```

In 1) or 2) you will have to reset the listener when switching back to playlist.

Personally, I would use two tables and hide one or the other based in the mode.

Answer (score 1):

> However, when I double click on the movies I get an empty table back.

- this has nothing to do with `MouseListener`, have to disable `TableCellEditor`

.

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
    return false; 
}
```

.

- have to test `if return -1` (any row is selected) for `int row = target.getSelectedRow();`
- this logics isn't correct why you enables whatever on `mouse_double_click`, disable `ListSelectionMode`,